# Share an AMI on my github?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm setting up an AMI that benchmarks a software project I'm doing. I want to share the AMI on github so that I can link to it from my paper and reviewers can just upload the AMI to EC2 and run the benchmarks, without any trouble. How can I do this? What are the exact steps to download my image, and what instructions should I give reviewers to upload and run the image?

Comment: In EC2, you can just create public AMIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me clear up something: you cannot download an AMI.

That said, you have two options:

1. Make your AMI public and publish its ID.
2. Publish an automated means of building your AMI.

There are pros and cons to both options. I generally prefer option #2, though, as it's more transparent. One can easily see exactly what is going into the AMI, without having to go spelunking through its filesystem.

Which of these works best for you will require enumerating your requirements and those of whom will be using the AMI, and with that information, choosing the best fit.